# What is a general way to prove isomorphism between groups with presentations?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be functions given by $f(x)=-x$ and $g(x)=x+1$. They are permutations of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $G$ be the group generated by $f$ and $g$. The group law is composition.

I am wondering whether there is a way to prove that this group $G$ is isomorphic to $H= \langle a,b\mid a^2=e,ab=b^{-1}a \rangle$. I can show that there exists a group homomorphism $\varphi:H\rightarrow G$ but these two groups seems to be both infinite so I need to find an inverse but I don't know how.

Comment: If you can prove the subgroups generated by the relators are the same...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to mse!

First things first, there's no *general* way to show that two presentations are isomorphic. This is the [isomoprhism problem for groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_isomorphism_problem), and it's "well known" to be [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem) in general.

That said, we *can* solve this particular example!

You've shown there's a group hom $\varphi : H \to G$, presumably by realizing that $f \circ f = \text{id}$ and $f \circ g = g^{-1} \circ f$. Since $f$ and $g$ generate $G$, and are in the image of $\varphi$, this means that $\varphi$ is surjective (do you see why?) so it remains to check that $\varphi$ is injective.

Here's a hint/sketch:

Can you show that every element of $G$ is of the form $f^{i} \circ g^{j}$ where $i \in \{0,1\}$ and $j \in \mathbb{Z}$? The crux of the argument is in showing that anytime we have a $g^n \circ f$, we can replace it by an $f \circ g^{-n}$ so that we end up with all our $f$s to the left of our $g$s.

Once you've done this, can you show that $f^{i} g^{j} = \text{id}$ if and only if $i = j = 0$? Here you'll finally want to use the fact that $f$ and $g$ are functions. If $i$ or $j$ is nonzero, can you show that some real must get moved? Moreover, can you show that $f^i g^j$ and $f^k g^l$ are different functions provided $(i,j) \neq (k, l)$?

Lastly, let's use this to check $\varphi$ is injective! Notice (by a similar argument to what we just did) every element of $H$ is of the form $a^i b^j$ for $i \in \{0,1\}$ and $j \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $\varphi(a^i b^j) = f^i g^j$, and now it should be easy to check injectivity.

As an aside, this worked by finding a [normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_form_(abstract_rewriting)) for the elements of $G$ and $H$. This mode of argument is incredibly flexible, and should be on your radar whenever you're doing combinatorics with words.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you so much.